# Docker start returns OCI runtime error - runc version mismatch

Tags: 20.04, docker

I am seeing a weird error on Ubuntu 20.04 when I run the docker using `docker run --name <container_id>`.

> docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
> ("failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI
> runtime create failed: runc create failed: unsupported spec
> (1.1.0-rc.2), need 1.0.x: unknown")

- Docker version - 24.0.5
- runc version - 1.1.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1

However, with docker version 20.10.21 and runc version 1.1.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.3, there are no issues. So, this problem might not be related to runc version.

Please let me know how I resolve it.